# Problems with presenting views in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I hope you can help me with my actual problems with designing an iPhone-App in the latest xCode version.

Here´s what I find a bit strange:

I designed a new project with a Storyboard and a Navigation Controller. Then I placed Objects like UILabels, ImageViews and so on. No when I run the Project in the simulator (as well on the iPhone) I noticed the following: When the App loads all the in the View placed objects fall down from the top to take their defined place. It takes maybe the quarter of a second, but its clearly to see. It also happens on all other views initiated from the root view controller

So, what do I have to change that everything is at it´s fixed place without to fall down from the top at the start of the app?

I hope I described it good enough. Actually I have no idea what´s going on there. I hope you can help me to fix this "problem". I´ve written some small Apps before, but I´ve never noticed a behavior like this.

Comment: I think I'm experiencing that also... I have a lot of animations in my app, so there is the chance that I just forgot I animated that, but so far as I know, I didn't and I'm having the same exact thing?

Comment: I don´t have much animations in my app, only four UIImageViews on the Mainscreen that rotate for a second...

Comment: you dont put anything on the navigation controller

Comment: I don´t realy put it onto the navigation controller, i meant the first accessable view which I can use with a navigation controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution: I´ve had to remove the animations on the main view... now it works proper! :-)